# Question about Options pattern and dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following code in the Startup code of one project:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services
        .AddAppCommonServices(configuration)
        .AddSingleton<IKeyVaultClient, KeyVaultClient>();
    
    IKeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IKeyVaultClient>();

    services.RegisterMonitoringTelemetry(keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(configuration[Consts.AppInsightsInstrumentationKey]).Result);

    ...
}
```

This is working fine. But since we recently updated the .NET Core version, we started getting a [warning message due to the call to the BuildServiceProvider()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0000?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method. I was looking for how to properly write the code above to avoid the problem described by the warning and I understand that the right way is to use the Options Pattern to inject the necessary values. However, while I understand the concept, I'm still confused on how to actually use it in my case.

I tried this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddOptions<KeyVaultClientSettings>()
        .Configure<IKeyVaultClient>((settings, kvc) =>
        {
            settings.Secret = kvc.GetSecretAsync(configuration[Consts.AppInsightsInstrumentationKey]).Result;
        }
    );

    services
        .AddAppCommonServices(configuration)
        .AddSingleton<IKeyVaultClient, KeyVaultClient>();
    
    services
        .Configure<KeyVaultClientSettings>(settings =>
        {
            services.RegisterMonitoringTelemetry(settings.Secret);
        });

    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work. From debugging, it seems that the RegisterMonitoringTelemetry method is never called, though I'm not sure why.

Any help on how to fix my code, I would be super thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I think the issue is because you didn't create a scope. However even this solution is not the best practice.
Calling async method in ConfigureServices with .Result is also kind of bad stuff.

```
using var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
var ketVaultClient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IKeyVaultClient>();
services.RegisterMonitoringTelemetry(keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(configuration[Consts.AppInsightsInstrumentationKey]).Result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But yeah, the underlying problem that causes the warning is the call to BuildServiceProvider, so with your suggestion the problem persists.

Comment: You can try to create a private method and accept IServiceCollection as a paramater.
Build service provider with scope there, receive your secret key from vault and return it from the method. Then in ConfigureServices you can add telimetry with received key. Don't forget to dispose the scope of service provider.